# jquery select option by text not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my code there are three `select` elements (one for each file) with 3 or 4 options each. I have added one Apply All button on the row having first file.

If an user selects the sheet name on the first file and clicks on `Apply All` button, it has to select same sheets on all the files. If the sheet was missing on anyone of the files, it has to show an alert like "mismatched sheets". Here is what I tried,

```
<form method="post" id="sheetForm" action="#"><input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="cR9fmhJk0hhQF0FIFscTABn3DXnXMPNPAOu2cZhSwFwRfC0FleEUJnlVsqbC2I4D">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="m-b-15">

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="m-b-30 form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Sheet Select Mode</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <label class="radio-inline">
                      <input type="radio" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1" name="radioInline">By Name
                  </label>
                  <label class="radio-inline">
                      <input type="radio" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2" name="radioInline">By Position
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <table id="tblPreview" class="table table-hover dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>File Name</th>
                    <th>Sheet Name</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                  <tr>
                    <td class="file-name">test-data-input-xls-mult-feb.xlsx</td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="filename" value="test-data-input-xls-mult-feb.xlsx">
                    <td>
                      <select id="select1" class="form-control input-small sheet-select" name="sheet-select">


                          <option value="name 1" selected="selected" >Sheet1</option>

                        <option value="index 1">1</option>


                          <option value="name 2">Sheet2</option>

                        <option value="index 2">2</option>

                    </select>
                    </td>
                    <td class="open">

                      <button type="button" id="btnApplyAll" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">Apply All Files </button>

                    </td>

                  </tr>


                  <tr>
                    <td class="file-name">test-data-input-xls-mult-jan.xlsx</td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="filename" value="test-data-input-xls-mult-jan.xlsx">
                    <td>
                      <select id="select2" class="form-control input-small sheet-select" name="sheet-select">


                          <option value="name 1" selected="selected">Sheet1</option>

                        <option value="index 1">1</option>


                          <option value="name 2" >Sheet2</option>

                        <option value="index 2" >2</option>

                    </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>

                    </td>

                  </tr>


                  <tr>
                    <td class="file-name">test-data-input-xls-mult-mar.xlsx</td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="filename" value="test-data-input-xls-mult-mar.xlsx">
                    <td>
                      <select id="select3" class="form-control input-small sheet-select" name="sheet-select">


                          <option value="name 1" selected="selected" >Sheet1</option>

                        <option value="index 1" >1</option>

                          <option value="name 2" >Sheet2</option>

                        <option value="index 2">2</option>

                    </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </form>
```

and the relevant js code looks like,

```
$('#btnApplyAll').on('click', function(){
    // get the selected option of first select
    var noSuchOption = false;
    var selectedOption = $('#select1').find(":selected").text();
    var selects = $('select[name="sheet-select"]');
    $('select[name="sheet-select"] option[selected="selected"]').removeAttr('selected');

    $.each(selects, function(index, select) {
      var opts = $(select).find('option').filter(function(){ return this.text == selectedOption;});
      if(opts.length < 1) {
        noSuchOption = true;
        return false;
      }
    });

    if(noSuchOption) {
      notify_long("Selected sheet doesn't exists in all files!", 'danger');
    } else {
        $('select[name="sheet-select"] option').filter(function(){
            return this.text == selectedOption;
        }).attr('selected', true);
    }
  });
```

This piece of code works on the initial stage of 3 or 4 button clicks but if I click on apply all button after choosing sheet1 on file1, sheet2 on file2, sheet1 on file3 at the middle stage, it fails to change. On that time, switching between radio buttons also fails to display the relevant option.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n4dchvy4/19/)

Comment: so do you want preserve selection while you change select sheet mode

Comment: @Dipakchavda no, If I choose position, all the selects should display 1,2 and the 1 option (first option) has to be selected and if I choose "name" it should list sheet1, sheet2 and sheet1 (first option) got selected. This works at the initial stage, but later it fails. I have tried adding setTimeout but it won't help.

Comment: Yes, Avinash will give me some time I shall give you working fiddle if possible after 2 3 hours.

Comment: oki, have you tried selecting the sheets from dropdown and cliicking the apply all button? It failed to work at the later stages (after 5 or more button clicks).

Comment: Why do all three selects have same name?

Comment: is that a problem? I think name attribute need not to be unique.

Comment: @AvinashRaj did you find anything wrong in my answer just let me know for my information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could meet your requirements:

```js
$('#btnApplyAll').on('click', function(){
    var noSuchOption = false;
    var selectedOption = null;
    $('select.sheet-select').each(function(index) {
      if (noSuchOption) return;
      if (index == 0) {
        selectedOption = $(this).val();
        return;
      }
      if ($(this).find('option[value="' + selectedOption + '"]').length === 0) {
        noSuchOption = true;
        alert("File: "+$(this).parent().prev().val() +" have not selected sheet", 'danger');
        return;
      }
      $(this).val(selectedOption);
    })
  });
  
 function toggleOptions(e) {
    var toggle = $(this).attr('id') == 'inlineRadio1' ? 'name' : 'index';
    $('select.sheet-select option').hide()
    $('select.sheet-select').each(function() {
      let optsToShow = $(this).find('option[value^="'+ toggle +'"]');
      optsToShow.show();
      $(this).val(optsToShow.first().attr('value'));
    });
  }

  $('#inlineRadio1, #inlineRadio2')
    .change(toggleOptions) 
    .first().change(); // trigger change to initialize
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="sheetForm" action="#">
   <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="cR9fmhJk0hhQF0FIFscTABn3DXnXMPNPAOu2cZhSwFwRfC0FleEUJnlVsqbC2I4D">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="m-b-30 form-group">
         <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Sheet Select Mode</label>
         <div class="col-md-8">
            <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1" name="radioInline" checked>By Name
            </label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2" name="radioInline">By Position
            </label>
         </div>
      </div>
      <table id="tblPreview" class="table table-hover dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>File Name</th>
               <th>Sheet Name</th>
               <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td class="file-name">test-data-input-xls-mult-feb.xlsx</td>
               <input type="hidden" name="filename" value="test-data-input-xls-mult-feb.xlsx">
               <td>
                  <select id="select1" class="form-control input-small sheet-select" name="sheet-select-feb">
                     <option value="name 1" selected="selected" >Sheet1</option>
                     <option value="index 1">1</option>
                     <option value="name 2">Sheet2</option>
                     <option value="index 2">2</option>
                     <option value="name 3">Sheet3</option>
                  </select>
               </td>
               <td class="open">
                  <button type="button" id="btnApplyAll" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">Apply All Files </button>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td class="file-name">test-data-input-xls-mult-jan.xlsx</td>
               <input type="hidden" name="filename" value="test-data-input-xls-mult-jan.xlsx">
               <td>
                  <select id="select2" class="form-control input-small sheet-select" name="sheet-select-jan">
                     <option value="name 1" selected="selected">Sheet1</option>
                     <option value="index 1">1</option>
                     <option value="name 2" >Sheet2</option>
                     <option value="index 2" >2</option>
                  </select>
               </td>
               <td>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td class="file-name">test-data-input-xls-mult-mar.xlsx</td>
               <input type="hidden" name="filename" value="test-data-input-xls-mult-mar.xlsx">
               <td>
                  <select id="select3" class="form-control input-small sheet-select" name="sheet-select-mar">
                     <option value="name 1" selected="selected" >Sheet1</option>
                     <option value="index 1">1</option>
                     <option value="name 2" >Sheet2</option>
                     <option value="index 2">2</option>
                  </select>
               </td>
               <td>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: seems like it's working.. May I know what I done wrong?

Comment: But no,, what's if the files having different sheet names? It should fail. We have to make use of text.

Comment: try adding `<option value="name 3">Sheet3</option>`, `<option value="name 3">Sheet3</option>`, `<option value="name 3">Sheet4</option>` for file1,2,3

Comment: Sorry but it does not make sense. Why would have same values different text?

Comment: @Avinash Raj if you are looking whats wrong in your code, its all about selected="selected" and using attr instead prop. If you want set selected, you do .prop('selected', true), false for unset...

Comment: I managed to include the sheetname inside the value attribute like `name sheet_name`, `id sheet_id` and in the selection I have done like `$=" selected_val.split()[1]"`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thank you for your patience. Please review my answer probably it will resolve an issue.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Default select mode of sheet
  $(".rdoSelection[value='byName']").prop("checked", true);
   
  function selectCheckboxstatus() {
    var selectionMode;    
    $(".clsDdPosition").prop("selectedIndex", 0);
    $(".clsDdName").prop("selectedIndex", 0);
    selectionMode = $(".rdoSelection:checked").val();
    if ("byName" === selectionMode) {
      $(".clsDdPosition").hide();
      $(".clsDdName").show();
    } else if ("byPosition" === selectionMode) {
      $(".clsDdPosition").show();
      $(".clsDdName").hide();
    }
  }
  
  selectCheckboxstatus();
  
  $(".rdoSelection").on("click", function(e) {
    selectCheckboxstatus();
  });

  $(".btnApplyAll").on("click", function(e) {
    var selectedValue, selectedClass, ddSelectionMode;
    ddSelectionMode = $(".rdoSelection:checked").val();     if ("byName" === ddSelectionMode) {
      selectedValue = $("#ddSheetByName1").val();
      selectedClass = ".clsDdName";
    } else if ("byPosition" === ddSelectionMode) {
      selectedValue = $("#ddSheetByPosition1").val();
      selectedClass = ".clsDdPosition";
    }    
    $(selectedClass).each(function() {
      $(this).val(selectedValue);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" id="sheetForm" action="#">
  <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="cR9fmhJk0hhQF0FIFscTABn3DXnXMPNPAOu2cZhSwFwRfC0FleEUJnlVsqbC2I4D">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="m-b-15">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="m-b-30 form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Sheet Select Mode</label>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" id="inlineRadio1" value="byName" name="radioInline" class="rdoSelection">By Name
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" id="inlineRadio2" value="byPosition" name="radioInline" class="rdoSelection">By Position
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <table id="tblPreview" class="table table-hover dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>File Name</th>
          <th>Sheet Name</th>
          <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="file-name">test-data-input-xls-mult-feb.xlsx</td>
          <input type="hidden" name="filename" value="test-data-input-xls-mult-feb.xlsx">
          <td>
            <select id="ddSheetByName1" class="form-control input-small ddSheetByName1 clsDdName" name="sheet-select">
              <option value="sheet1">Sheet1</option>
              <option value="sheet2">Sheet2</option>
            </select>
            <select id="ddSheetByPosition1" class="form-control input-small ddSheetByPosition1 clsDdPosition" name="sheet-select">
              <option value="index1">1</option>
              <option value="index2">2</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td class="open">
            <button type="button" id="btnApplyAll" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btnApplyAll" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">Apply All Files </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="file-name">test-data-input-xls-mult-jan.xlsx</td>
          <input type="hidden" name="filename" value="test-data-input-xls-mult-jan.xlsx">
          <td>
            <select id="ddSheetByName2" class="form-control input-small ddSheetByName2 clsDdName" name="sheet-select">
              <option value="sheet1">Sheet1</option>
              <option value="sheet2">Sheet2</option>
            </select>
            <select id="ddSheetByPosition2" class="form-control input-small ddSheetByPosition2 clsDdPosition" name="sheet-select">
              <option value="index1">1</option>
              <option value="index2">2</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="file-name">test-data-input-xls-mult-mar.xlsx</td>
          <input type="hidden" name="filename" value="test-data-input-xls-mult-mar.xlsx">
          <td>
            <select id="ddSheetByName3" class="form-control input-small ddSheetByName3 clsDdName" name="sheet-select">
              <option value="sheet1">Sheet1</option>
              <option value="sheet2">Sheet2</option>
            </select>
            <select id="ddSheetByPosition3" class="form-control input-small ddSheetByPosition3 clsDdPosition" name="sheet-select">
              <option value="index1">1</option>
              <option value="index2">2</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</form>
```